# ClassNotFoundException when tring to store trigger in Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, spring, osgi, quartz-scheduler

Need help on Quartz scheduler. This is what I have done so far.

Spring  definition

```
<bean id="firstClass" class="com.my.sample.FirstClass">
    // some properties
</bean>

<bean id="secondClass" class="com.my.sample.SecondClass">
    // some properties
</bean>

<bean id="myJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.my.sample.quartz.job.MyJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="firstClass" value-ref="firstClass" />
            <entry key="secondClass" value-ref="secondClass" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="10000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="quartzProperties" ref="quartzProperties" />
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list><ref bean="myJob" /></list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list><ref bean="simpleTrigger" /></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

class implementations

```
public class MyJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJob.class);

    private FirstClass firstClass;
    private SecondClass secondClass;

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(final JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        LOGGER.info("Executing job...");

        final AbcClass abcClass = firstClass.getAbc();
        secondClass.testMethod(abcClass);

    }

    public void setFirstClass(final FirstClass firstClass) {
        this.firstClass = firstClass;
    }

    public void setSecondClass(final SecondClass secondClass) {
        this.secondClass = secondClass;
    }
}

public interface MyParent {

    AbcClass getAbc();

}

public class FirstClass implements MyParent, Serializable {

    AbcClass getAbc() {
        // generate abcClass from db

        return abcClass;
    }

}
```

but I'm getting error like this

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' defined in URL [bundle://343.0:0/META-INF/spring/osgi.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'simpleTrigger' for 'dataSyncJob' job:com.my.sample.MyParent [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.sample.MyParent]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)[428:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>   ...

project structure

```
com.my
    |-sample
        |-MyParent.java
        |-FirstClass.java
        |-SecondClass.java
        |-quartz.job
            |-MyJob.java
    |-other
```

bundle configurations

```
<configuration>
    <instructions>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Import-Package>
            org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle,
            org.quartz.simpl,
            org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore,
            *
        </Import-Package>
        <Export-Package>com.my.*</Export-Package>
        <excludeDependencies>*;scope=provided|runtime</excludeDependencies>
        <DynamicImport-Package>
            org.apache.cxf.*,
            org.springframework.beans.*
        </DynamicImport-Package>
    </instructions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Which version of spring are you using and also could you  post full stacktrace?

Comment: spring 3.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: Well information is pretty obvious. You do not have MyParent class.

Comment: @wawek I have MyParent interface

Comment: Show me the bean decalartion of firstClass and secondClass. You can add it to your question.

Comment: @AmitBhati it just like normal bean declaration

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.sample.MyParent` check the package and verify if the generated class file is in correct place

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you're doing osgi, you need to ensure:

1. The bundle containing the class com.my.sample.MyParent has been deployed.
2. The bundle using class MyParent imports the package com.my.sample in the MANIFEST.MF file under the Import-Package section.

If you are using Maven, then you can manipulate the MANIFEST.MF file with the Apache Felix [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).

Comment: Yes. I'm doing osgi. 
I have everything in one bundle.
I' using maven-bundle-plugin.

Comment: Could I see a tree diagram of your project structure?

Comment: I add to the question. Is that what you asking?

Comment: The layout of your source files is not that interesting. At runtime nobody is looking for source code. More useful would be the layout of the JAR content.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps you bundle configuration settings as well.

Comment: @ConMan add it as well

Comment: afaik the <excludeDependencies> is not required, as provided and runtime scoped dependencies are never packaged with your artifact

Comment: Just a few more thing: You should probably be importing the package org.springframework.scheduling.quartz - the bundle plugin is not very good at determining required imports from your spring configuration files, it only really works for java classes and blueprint xml files (sort of, I still get issues every now and then).  Also im not a fan of dynamic importing - it should only really be used if you dont know what you need until runtime, which is very very rare.  If you're using cxf and spring beans, then you should definately know what you need to use!